# Direct system where all maps are injections

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, limits-colimits

Is there a special name for a [direct system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit) where all the maps are injections?

It seems like people often write the direct limit of such a system as a union: e.g., "$S_\infty = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} S_n$," where $S_n$ are the finite symmetric groups, and $S_\infty$ is the group of permutations of $\{1,2,\ldots\}$ which fix all but finitely many elements.

This union notation is intuitive, but I wonder if there is a more formal name/notation for this situation. Obviously, it is the simplest kind of direct limit to think about.

Comment: I'm not trying to suggest a different question, but there are natural contexts where the morphisms simply are injections and so all the direct systems are of this type. For example, the category whose objects are integral domains and whose morphisms are the injective ring homomorphisms.  Another one might be $\mathcal P(X)$ with inclusion morphisms. Point is I guess sometimes it might be a matter of choice of category rather than "special direct system."